# Rebuilding deprecated sqlite functionality from MVVMCross to Community.Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, mvvmcross

The following code no longer registers correctly with the IOC. I am currently trying to switch to the Community.Plugins.Sqlite library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite;
using FlashCardApp.Core.Entities;
using FlashCardApp.Core.Managers.FlashCardApp.Core.Services;
using FlashCardApp.Core.ViewModels.Dictionary;


namespace FlashCardApp.Core.Managers
{
    class EnglishManager : IEnglishManager
    {
        private readonly ISQLiteConnection _connection;

        public EnglishManager(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
        {
            _connection = factory.Create("Dictionary.sqlite");
          // _connection.CreateTable<English>();
        }
```

I get the following stack trace error

mvx:Warning:  2.06 Problem creating viewModel of type DictionaryViewModel - problem MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter factory of type ISQLiteConnectionFactory when creating FlashCardApp.Core.Managers.EnglishManager at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues(Type type, ConstructorInfo firstConstructor)

How does one go about registering an ISQLiteConnectionFactory in a constructor. Or is there a new method of using this factory under the community plugin?

Edit: I added the community.sqlite plugin to my app.store project and now the ISQLFactory seems to be registering and creating but I get the following error

A first chance exception of type 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' occurred in Cirrious.MvvmCross.Community.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.DLL
'FlashCardApp.Store.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'

and

Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_win32_set_directory' in DLL 'sqlite3'.

Thanks in advance 
JH